# Error in android Studio 3.0 when I sync gradle. Error:Cause: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-studio-3.0, android-gradle-3.0

I got the following Error in android Studio 3.0,when I sync gradle.

Gradle 'Projectname' project refresh failed.

> Error:Cause: unable to find valid certification path to requested
>   target

Answer (score 5):

Delete `jcenter()` and Change The Repositories in the `build.gradle` file to the following format:

```
repositories {
    maven {
        url "http://jcenter.bintray.com"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had faced exact same issue to my existing projects after upgrading Android Studio 3.0.
I was able to resolve it with changing gradle script like below.

### build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:**3.0.0**'
    }
}
```

---

### gradle-wrapper.properties

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/**gradle-4.1-all.zip**
```

I hope this is helpful for you

Note: My Android Studio info

> Android Studio 3.0
>   Build #AI-171.4408382, built on October 21, 2017
>   JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-915-b01 amd64
>   JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
>   Windows 7 6.1